# Render doesn't match Camera View

Tags: rendering, camera

I have a single camera. I've set it up in camera view and it looks perfect. When I render, the view is skewed to the left. The scene has just a few objects in it.

Any ideas?

**Camera View:**

[image: Camera View]

**Render Output**

[image: Render Output]

Comment: Could be a couple things, Check to make sure you dont have 2 different cameras, and also check to make sure you dont have animation on your camera that is being reset to beginning when you go to render.

Comment: Holy crap! You're right. It was an animation. TY!

Comment: That happens to me all the time, drives me crazy. lol.